# "I'll have one" or "I'll have it."

Tags: word-choice

I basically know the difference between "one" and "it".  But how about the example below?

(in a restaurant)

- Customer: What's your recommendation today?
- Sever: Our steak tartare is the best.
- Customer: OK.  **I'll have (one/it).**

What would you say when you order something that has been recommended?

Answer (score 1):

"*I'll have one.*" is basically short for "I'll have one of those".  In this context, either might be used, and the meaning would be much the same. "I'll have that" or "Yes, I'll have the teak tartare" would also carry the same meaning. So would "That sounds good. Bring me that please".